# How can i redirect to previous page after a form submit in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, http-redirect

I have a test function in controller which generates a form page.

```
public function testing()
    {  
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('test', 'TEST', 'required');

               if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                redirect($this->agent->referrer());
               } else {
                $data['title'] = 'Testing';
                $data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('pages/nonmember/testing', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
               }         
    }
```

The code of testing view as below

```
<div id="message"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
<?php echo form_open(base_url()."testing");?>

  <p> 
    <?php echo form_input('test');?>
  </p>

  <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?></p>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

If users come from another page lets say `About page` to testing page i want after submitting form properly they get redirected back to `About page`. But it is not being possible as referer agent is staying at the `testing page`, so after submit it is staying there and not redirecting to `About page`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your controller's testing function

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('url',$this->agent->referrer());
```

change this in the function **testing**

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      redirect($this->session->flashdata('url'));
    } else {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('url',$this->agent->referrer());
       //load the view
    }
...
```

or you can also submit an hidden field like,

```
form_hidden('rURL', $this->agent->referrer());
```

then simply use its value in the controller.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
          redirect($this->input->post('rURL'));
        } else {
    ...
```

Comment: First of all it is `set_flashdata()`. Secondly both solutions will work but if users refresh testing page after landing on it or user inputs don't obey validation rules then the page will be refreshed meaning referrer becomes itself, so testing page redirecting back to itself

Comment: Nothing will work if users input wrong data or refresh the testing page , after comming from another page. With page refresh referer is changing from other page's url to testing page's url.

Comment: I thought you can handle this issue.

I'll write detailed code example soon.

Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is the best solution or not , but i found the solution working perfectly.

We need to write the referrer address in a file and to redirect we need to read from that file.
first we need to load the file helper.

```
$this->load->helper('file');

if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    redirect(read_file('referrer.php'));
}
else
{
    $referrer = $this->agent->referrer();
    //need to check wrong input submission and page refresh
     if ($referrer != "http://localhost/CIpractice2/testing"  && !empty($referrer))
      {
          write_file('referrer.php', $referrer);
      }
  //show the form
}
```

Please refer to codeIgniter's [file helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) documentation

Comment: sessions should be preferred - with a file, simultaneous users would interfere with each other